# Visual Studio 2008 Add Service Reference Error - WSDL - Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved

Tags: visual-studio-2008, wsdl, soapui

I have a web service running on a server on the local network. Using the program soapUI, I am able to connect to the service no problem. So when I create a new project using soapUI and type in my url 'http://xx.xx.xx.xx:9180/SOAOICCT/services/SessionService?wsdl' it loads up no problem.

When I try to Add Service Reference in Visual Studio 2008 using the same URL I get a 'Add Service Reference Error':

```
There was an error downloading 'http://xx.xx.xx.xx:9180/SOAOICCT/services/SessionService?wsdl'.
The request failed with HTTP status 504: Gateway Timeout.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://47.166.94.33:9180/SOAOICCT/services/SessionService?wsdl'.
The remote server returned an error: (504) Gateway Timeout.
The remote server returned an error: (504) Gateway Timeout.
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.
```

When I try and use the wsdl.exe command from the visual studio command prompt I get the an error:
[image]

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% what the problem was but here is a summary of the fix.

The problem was with the host name. On the server, the host name was 'cs1ktest' but visual studio thought the host name was 47.166.94.33

So, I updated the host file and added a line

```
47.166.94.33    cs1ktest
```

and I tried the wsdl.exe again, replacing the ip address with 'cs1ktest' and BOOM!!!

[image]

it worked.